# how to remove zombie unit-mounts from my KDE system?

Tags: mount, boot, opera

I've recently removed opera-developer from my kde-neon system, however I still see mounts from unit-mount nodes for opera-developer revisions 80, 68, and 90. These per-static mounts are slowing down the boot process. How do I remove them completely?

Answer (score 0):

It's all part of the snap package management platform.  Removing the software doesn't necessary clean up old snap mounts. Use `mount` to see all the snaps that are installed and that get started at boot time. You can also see them listed under the `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/` directory.

Remove unneeded snaps with:

```
snap remove --purge opera-developer
```